# Como conocer el indice de una sublista dentro de una lista

Tags: python

Ocupo conocer el indice de una sublista para contar los valores que hay en ella y luego agregarlos a un total, si conocen algún método sería de mucha ayuda.

Acá lo que tengo hecho

```
def contar(lista):
totalLista=0
for i in lista:
    cantidadSub=lista.count(i)
    if cantidadSub==1:
        totalLista+=1
        print(totalLista)
        return contar(lista[:4])
    else:
        totalLista+=cantidadSub
        print(totalLista)
```

contar([1,2,3,5,4,[1,5,4]])

La idea es que por cada elemento sume 1 al totalLista, y al encontrarse una sublista, sume la cantidad de datos que haya en la sublista al totalLista

Comment: Hola Brandon, en la pregunta no queda muy claro lo que buscas, quieres conocer el índice de una sublista en una lista ¿a partir de qué información?¿buscar en un índice concreto de todas las sublistas un valor?¿buscar un valor en todos los items de las sublistas?¿O solo quieres hacer una sumatoria de las sublistas? Si agregas un [mcve] y el código que has intentado a tus preguntas siempre recibirás respuestas más rápidamente, más precisas y adecuadas a tu caso concreto. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontre esta forma de hacerlo

```
test_list = [[1, 'lista'], [2, 'unidad'], [3, 'prueba']]  

res = [ele for i, ele in test_list].index('unidad') 
  
print("Index del elemento : " + str(res)) 

sizelist = len(test_list[res])

print("Tamaño del elemento : " + str(sizelist))
```

Lo que hace es buscar un elemento dentro de la lista y despues obtiene el tamaño de la lista que lo contiene, puedes ver el [Python | Indexing a sublist](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-indexing-a-sublist/)

## Edición

Para contar elementos de una lista sin conocer sus elementos y pudiendo tener *n* cantidad de listas dentro de la lista padre o incluso de las listas hijos, se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
def contar(lista):
    totalLista=0
    for i in lista:
        if(type(i) is list):
            totalLista += contar(i)
        else:
            totalLista += 1
    return totalLista
print(contar([1,2,3,5,4,[1,5,[1,2,[1,2,3],3],4]]))
```

Comment: Olvidé indicar que no se conoce el contenido de la sublista, ni el indice en el que aparecerá la sublista

Comment: Eso cambia completamente las cosas, seria necesario que muestres como creas las listas.

Comment: La lista se crea al llamar la función, en:
contar([1,2,3,[3,6,7],4,8,[2,[2,5]]])

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta, espero te funcione

Comment: Funciona perfecto! Gracias